# Oracle pl/sql ORA-00904 invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to pl/sql and I cannot figure out what is the problem in the following scripts. First I executed this script:

```
CREATE TABLE Cladiri (
 id_cladire varchar2(5) constraint pk_cladire primary key,
 denumire_cladire varchar2(50),
 numar_cladire number(2),
 adresa varchar2(50),
 cod_postal varchar2(15)
);
```

Which created successfully a table. Next, I want to create a new table with a foreign key referencing `id_cladire`:

```
CREATE TABLE Companii (
    id_companie varchar2(5) constraint pk_companie primary key,
    denumire_companie varchar2(50),
    numar_cladire number(4),
    numarul_de_telefon varchar2(20),
    numarul_de_oficii number(4),
    constraint fk_companie_cladire foreign key (id_cladire) references 
Cladiri(id_cladire)
);
```

and I get the following error when executing the last script:

> ORA-00904: "ID_CLADIRE": invalid identifier

What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add column `id_cladire` to `Companii` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Companii (
    id_companie varchar2(5) constraint pk_companie primary key,
    denumire_companie varchar2(50),
    numar_cladire number(4),
    numarul_de_telefon varchar2(20),
    numarul_de_oficii number(4),
    id_cladire VARCHAR2(5), -- here
    constraint fk_companie_cladire foreign key (id_cladire) references 
Cladiri(id_cladire)
);
    -- column + type + constraint
```

or:

```
CREATE TABLE Companii (
    id_companie varchar2(5) constraint pk_companie primary key,
    denumire_companie varchar2(50),
    numar_cladire number(4),
    numarul_de_telefon varchar2(20),
    numarul_de_oficii number(4),
    id_cladire  CONSTRAINT fk_companie_cladire references Cladiri(id_cladire)
    -- column + constraint (type is inferred)
);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c151c32109e60963aefa8111b2bdb6f2)**

Comment: Extremly stupid mistake. Thank you very much! I will accept the answer in 10 mins